# How to extract a decimal in a particular form from string in Python?

Tags: python, string

I will give an example (python 3.6) string which is typical of the data I am processing:

```
<TD class="tr26 td253"><P class="p103 ft3">0.7</P></TD>
```

This string is actually a substring, and the length of the string is highly variable. This is HTML that I am extracting as well.

I want to somehow extract the "0.7" from this string. How would I code it so that it can extract *any* decimal of the form "x.y" (e.g. 0.3, 2.1, 5.3) -- **These numbers are always between 0.0 and 9.0, so no need to worry about tens digits.**

Comment: Regex? String methods? Parsers? String containment of the just 99 possibilities? There are countless ways to do this. What are the cases you do *not* want to match? Why do you want to manually match the string instead of using a HTML library?

Comment: If that's the case `>\d.\d<` should match the required substring

Comment: @Don'tAccept that gives me an empty list.

Comment: I guess there are some empty space characters use `\s*` along with above regex

Comment: @Don'tAccept  I fixed it actually. Twas just a missing character. Thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it, using only what you have given us:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""<TD class="tr26 td253"><P class="p103 ft3">0.7</P></TD>""", "lxml")
>>> soup.find("p", {"class": "p103 ft3"}).text
'0.7'
```

Answer (score 0):

use **ElementTree**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
a = '<TD class="tr26 td253"><P class="p103 ft3">0.7</P></TD>'
tree = ET.fromstring(a)
value = tree[0].text
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `'>\s*(\d\.\d)\s*<'`, it will find any decimal number after `>` and before `<`, then will give you the required decimal number

```py
>>> import re
>>> text = '<TD class="tr26 td253"><P class="p103 ft3">0.7</P></TD>'
>>> re.findall('>\s*(\d\.\d)\s*<', text)
['0.7']
```